# Custom Validations in simple_form without model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a `simple_form` which isn't really on a model per se. I'm using:

```
simple_form_for(:client_emails,.....)
```

This works. it comes out the other side, goes to the correct controller, and has a params['client_emails'] with the correct stuff in it.

However, there are two fields, oldDomain and newDomain. I'd like to make sure that there are no clients with the same domain as newDomain. Is there a way to use simple_form's `f.error` functionality? or do I have to have the controller redirect to a separate error page once the problem has been detected?

Comment: If I get the point, could you create a model with no table including active model validations?

Comment: Maybe? The validations would have to do with things in the Client model... Is that a thing that validations can do?

Comment: You can just `include ActiveModel` in any 'ol PORO and SimpleForm should pick up the relevant bits.

Comment: `f.error` picks up errors generated in model by validations. --- If your model is related to a database table, look here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html --- If you need a model with no table look: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html (as @JoshBrody stated, `include ActiveModel` carries also validations)